# Webpack Error with --entry How do I fix this? Imports are not working

Tags: javascript, web, webpack

So I typed this into my terminal node_modules/.bin/webpack --entry ./src/index.js -o dist and it returns this error

\node_modules.bin\webpack.ps1 cannot be loaded because running scripts is
disabled on this system. For more information, see about_Execution_Policies at https:/go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135170.
At line:1 char:1

- node_modules/.bin/webpack --entry ./src/index.js -o dist
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : SecurityError: (:) [], PSSecurityException
  ```

I expected to use webpack and this commannd would allow me to import everything for it but it did not work.